# Send xmlhttprequest to a server through another server

Tags: javascript

I have tow servers (server A and B) which can communicate between them and a client that is able to communicate just with sever A and not with B. so I want to known if it is possible to send xmlhttprequest from the client to server A first and after that the server A resend this xmlhttprequest to server B. Client ==》 server A ==》 server B . Iam using javascript in my html web page.

Comment: you need to set up a proxy

Comment: Thanks Rene, can I use apache mod-proxy or that exist another solution?

Comment: What do you need the clients to send?  Post or Get data?  Could you tell a little more about what the goal is?

Comment: Yes I need the client to send and the request is like this "xhr.open (get, url)" using xmlhttprequest. The url contain ip address of server B and the client doesn't know how to reach this ip address but the server A can reach B .also you need to know that the client can access to server A so I want to send this request from the client to server B via serverA.